# Visiting "Downvoted" questions

Tags: discussion, flags, downvotes

I have a tendency to visit downvoted questions and check whether they deserve a downvote or maybe needs to be flagged. If they do, I downvote them further and/or flag them, otherwise I just leave them be. What I want to know is are all three of these desirable behavior?

1. Visiting downvoted questions with this intention
2. Downvoting them furthur or flagging them(**Edit**:If it needs to be)
3. Leaving them be(should I upvote them?)

Comment: You should upvote if a question merits an upvote (well-researched, well-written etc), not to rectify a downvote.

Comment: @dandan78: Yeah this 'fixing' thing does comes to mind but upvoting them also just doesn't feel right. Now i know exactly what to do. Thanks

Comment: @AlokChaudhary remember that the downvote is for the question/answer not for the author. So, no need to feel bad for a question that is downvoted "unnecessarily". *Fixing* a downvote with an upvote without actually wanting to upvote the question, means saying that the opinion of the downvoter should not be voiced.

Comment: I do sometimes find myself voting up if I thought a question has attracted a score it did not deserve. For example, an interesting question that has clearly had research and effort put into it, but is slightly discursive and heading for closure - in these cases I might +1 even though I might not vote to reopen. Ultimately, there are some grey areas - you can vote pretty much how you want, as long as you don't serial vote based on user.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Provided that you use your own judgement rather than find reasons to downvote and vote to close *merely* because there are already downvotes, then, taking your points in turn:

1. Please do visit a downvoted question to see whether it should be closed, and act towards closure if closure is warranted. Many users do not know that even if they do not yet have the reputation to cast close-votes they can flag the question for closure. They just downvote and move on. Flagging to close is going to put the question it the review queue.
2. Adding a donwvote if the question warrants a downvote is also useful to keep the site clean. People at 20k rep or over can immediately cast delete votes on a closed question if it is a -3 score or less. Some questions are so bad and cannot be fixed: they should be deleted immediately. (Note, *replacing* a question with an entirely new one is not "fixing". Questions that can be fixed should not be deleted immediately but those that require being turned into a new question to be on-topic should be deleted ASAP.)
3. If the question is one for which you would have not voted up or down if you had just come across it irrespective of its score or that you do not find is worthy of closure, then don't cast votes or flag. In particular **do not counter other upvotes or downvotes with your vote only because you disagree with the other votes.**

Comment: Yeah this does clarify it and with proper reasoning. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

As to 1, you can visit whichever questions you feel like.

You should **only** vote based on the **content** of the post -- not downvoting because someone else thought it was bad, or upvoting to 'fix' a downvote.

[image]

(Originally from https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/please-dont-misuse-the-voting-system/7241#7241)